# Given $f$ holomorphic on the unit disk, $|f(z)|\leq M$, prove $|f'(z)|\leq M(1-|z|)^{-1}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem: Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk and $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z$ in the unit disk.  Prove that $|f'(z)|\leq M(1-|z|)^{-1}$ for all $z$ in the unit disk.

Using a generalized version of the Schwarz lemma, I can prove that $|f'(z)|\leq M(1-|z|^2)^{-1}$ on the unit disk, however I cannot see a way to prove the inequality that is asked for.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using Schwarz-Pick Lemma?

Comment: Cauchy integral formula

Comment: isn't this Koebe's distortion theorem ?

Comment: Thanks, the Cauchy integral formula did it. Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier...